# MVC4 Get Route Data From ApiController

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I'm looking to grab the {contract} value out of my route when I hit my API controller.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{contract}/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

So when a user hits /api/rearch/allergies/1234 I'd like to grab "rearch" and use it to fetch a connection string.

I've attempted using RouteData and RouteTable like below with no luck:

```
this.RouteData.Values["contract"].ToString() 
RouteTable.Routes["contract"]
```

Is there something I'm missing?  Is this different in an ApiController?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab this out of the method's parameters... if you can change those:

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("ActionName_IfDifferentThanMethodName")]
public HttpResonseMessage method(string contract, int id)
{
  string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[contract];
}
```